# (list ...) vs '(...) in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, evaluation, quote

When I have a function definition `make-cd` and execute the function to get the wrong answer.

```
(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  '(:title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))

(add-record (make-cd "Roses" "Kathy Mattea" 7 t))

(:TITLE TITLE :ARTIST ARTIST :RATING RATING :RIPPED RIPPED)
```

I should have used `(list ...)` to get a correct answer.

```
(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))

(add-record (make-cd "Roses" "Kathy Mattea" 7 t))

(:TITLE "Roses" :ARTIST "Kathy Mattea" :RATING 7 :RIPPED T)
```

Why is this?

Comment: `'(X Y Z)` is shorthand for `(QUOTE (X Y Z))`. [`QUOTE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm) simply returns the given object as literal data instead of evaluating it. That is, in your example `TITLE`, `ARTIST`, `RATING` and `RIPPED` aren't references to the variables with those names; they are just literal symbols.

Comment: It's like the difference between constant strings that don't interpolate `'this is $WYSIWYG' // => 'this is $WYSIWYG'` and strings that do `"This is not $WYSIWYG" // => "This is not replaced"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lisp has symbols as a data structure. Symbols can be used as themselves - as symbols - or as variables in code.

You need to remember the evaluation rules for quoted expressions and function calls:

**Evaluation rule for quoted expression**: nothing inside a quoted expression is evaluated. The value is returned as is.

**Evaluation rule for function calls**: with a function call, all arguments are evaluated left-to-right and these results passed to the function. The computation results of the function are being returned.

**Creating data**:

A quoted symbol:

```
CL-USER 13 > 'foo
FOO
```

A quoted list. Nothing inside the quote is evaluated.

```
CL-USER 14 > '(foo bar)
(FOO BAR)
```

A nested list, quoted.

```
CL-USER 15 > '((foo bar) (foo baz))
((FOO BAR) (FOO BAZ))
```

A freshly created list using the function `list`. The contents are symbols.

```
CL-USER 16 > (list 'foo 'bar)
(FOO BAR)
```

A freshly created nested list:

```
CL-USER 17 > (list (list 'foo 'bar) (list 'foo 'bar))
((FOO BAR) (FOO BAR))
```

A freshly created list, using quoted lists as contents:

```
CL-USER 18 > (list '(foo bar) '(foo bar))
((FOO BAR) (FOO BAR))
```

**Creating data, using variables**:

Using the function `list` with two variables:

```
CL-USER 19 > (let ((foo 1)
                   (bar 2))
               (list foo bar))
(1 2)
```

Using a *backquoted* list. The elements after the comma are evaluated.

```
CL-USER 20 > (let ((foo 1)
                   (bar 2))
               `(,foo ,bar))
(1 2)
```

Using a nested *backquoted* list. The elements after the comma are evaluated.

```
CL-USER 21 > (let ((foo 1)
                   (bar 2))
               `((,foo ,bar) (,foo ,bar)))
((1 2) (1 2))
```